# Python permutations, variable survives recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have a problem with my code.

Variable "used" survives recursion (it doesn't return to before state, but stays the same).

I understand this is common for default variable, however, "used" shouldn't be default now.

**Can somebody explain how does it happen?**

```
newArray = []


def permutations(used, default=None):
    if default is None:
        default = used
        used = []
    if len(used) == len(default):
        newArray.append(used)
        return
    else:
        for i in range(len(default)):
            if default[i] in used:
            continue
        used.append(default[i])
        permutations(used, default)
print(permutations(['1', '2', '3']))
```

Comment: You're passing a mutable object into the recursion, where it is mutated.

Comment: Note: `len(default)`, `def permutations(used, default=None):` and `permutations(['1', '2', '3'])`don't exactly work together.

Comment: Well yeah, I wanted to use this mutable object "default" to stay practically constant for the whole time if it isn't None. But, do I understand it right, did "used" become mutable also?

Comment: Duplicate of your own https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215650/python-permutations-variable-survives-recursion

Comment: CristiFati, what exactly do you mean?
Stefan Pochmann, it shouldn't be duplicate. Yes, I posted it, but the algorithm I use changed. In the before post, I wanted mutable object to return to before state, now I rather wanted to use it to stay same the whole time once it's changed and change variable 'used' which I thought would act like a normal variable under recursion

Comment: @DavidBulko Changed? It's byte for byte the *exact same code*.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Oh yeah, sorry, it was different. I changed it to this one, but I figured out that since the before one was tagged as duplicate of mutable variables post I should as well create new one

Comment: Is this algorithm even possible?